# How to deny to access to external storage programmatically?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on a privileged app with system permissions. I need to deny user access to external storage (SD card). I've used `UserManager` for this purpose. It works for other privileges like disallow Bluetooth configuration, Wifi configuration etc, but it doesn't work for  `UserManager.DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA`

I've used following code to access method:

```
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(getUserManagerStub(),"setUserRestriction",new Object[]{key,value,userId});
```

Answer (score 0):

with the [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager) there's `.addUserRestriction()` & `.clearUserRestriction()`.

this should support flags `DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA` & `DISALLOW_USB_FILE_TRANSFER`.

Comment: thanks but is it possible some methods works and some does not?

Comment: @AmirhoseinHeydari method invocation is not the official way to access the methods; it's not even certain the parameters are correct. `set` might even do something else than `add`.